# Can't read nested array json using JSRender

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates, jsrender

Can't read nested array json using JSRender

Code in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skystar3/aLsaL/)

I am getting

> Error: Error: Cannot read property 'person' of undefined. Error: Cannot read property 'person' of undefined.

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a line in there:

```
{{for list.person.phones}}
```

Which is already inside the `person` loop (so would be looking for a `list` object inside your `person` object), and doesn't match the layout of your data anyway, so it's causing the error.  Change that block to:

```
{{for numbers}}
    {{for phones}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{:name}}</td>
            <td>{{:number}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/for}}
{{/for}}
```

and it works.